# firefox / html5 video /wifi

Tags: wireless, firefox, video, html5

Got the strangest experience.  Firefox on Ubuntu (14.04) does not play html5 video (eg YouTube) it plays a few frames and then stops.  When I disable my wifi adapter (button or software disable does not matter) it plays along till it hits the already buffered video limit.  Tried all sorts of upgrades (even a 16.04 one) but still got the same results.  Any ideas?

Chrome seems to work just fine by the way...

thx

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Somehow, firefox tried to stream the audio to some airplay speakers on the network. (something that actually never worked).  This caused the video to stall.  Killing the WIFI (network) allowed the video to play and send audio to the local device, re-enableling the network caused it to stall again...